# MySQL: Can't create table './myhairdev/catalog_product_index_website.frm' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, utf-8

I keep getting this error while trying to import my website database to another server.

**error:**

```
Error at the line 3034: ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Website Index Table';
```

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website` (
`website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website ID',
`website_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Date',
`rate` float DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Rate',
PRIMARY KEY (`website_id`),
KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_DATE` (`website_date`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_WS_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Website Index Table'

MySQL: Can't create table './myhairdev/catalog_product_index_website.frm' (errno: 150)
```

I tried to add `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` at the beginning  and SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; at the end but still getting the same error.

Here is the code in the related database line:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog_product_index_website`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website` (
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website ID',
  `website_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Date',
  `rate` float DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Rate',
  PRIMARY KEY (`website_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_DATE` (`website_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_WS_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Website Index Table';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Help Help please :)

Comment: Err 150 is often a data type mismatch between the referenced and referencing column in a FK relationship.  You only have one of the tables above -  make sure that `website_id` is `smallint(5) unsigned` in _both_ of the tables, and that `catalog_product_index_website` is created after `core_website`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove the constraint

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_WS_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

and add it at the end, when all the tables, primary keys and indexes are created.

In your case, you have to create the table `core_website` and declare the column `website_id` as an index before creating a foreign key related to this index and this table.